# Comparación de caracteres con arreglos en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un código que le pide al usuario una letra y la letra ingresado por el usuario, se vaya comparando en un arreglo/matriz linea por linea, si la letra no esta en esa posición del arreglo, se rellene con un **-**, el problema es que no compara o algo hice mal.
Aquí les dejo un ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char palabras[20][13]={"ornitorrinco"};
char palabras2[20][13];
void comparacion (int j,int letras,char caracter)

{
    while (letras>j)
    {
        if (caracter==palabras[0][j])
        {
            palabras2[0][j]=caracter;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            palabras2[0][j]='-';
            j++;
        }

    }
    printf("%s",palabras2[0]);
}
int main()
{
    int contador,letras,j,intentos;
    char caracter;
    contador=0;
    intentos=5;
    letras=strlen(palabras[0]);
    while (contador<intentos)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Ingrese un caracter: \n");
        scanf("%c",&caracter);
        j=0;
        comparacion(j,letras,caracter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Como pueden ver, hice una función llamada **comparación**, pero el problema es el siguiente:

```
Ingrese un caracter:
```

**Ingreso el caracter (letra o)  y sale lo siguiente**

```
o----o-----o
```

**De momento vamos bien, el error viene ahora:**

```
Ingrese un caracter:
------------    (Me salen estos guiones y no se por que salen)
```

**Ingreso el caracter (letra r) y sale esto:**

```
-r----rr----
```

Lo que yo quiero que salga, es esto:

```
or---orr---o
```

Pero no se por que, no se guardan las letras, siendo que lo guarde en **palabras2**
¿Alguna idea de por que este pasando esto?

Comment: El primer problema que tienes es que siempre que ingresas en la función comparacion, esta pisa toda la información que hay cambiándola por el caracter, en caso de que coincida, o por un guión, en caso de que no coincida. Por eso en cada llamada a la función solo aparece la secuencia de caracteres coincidentes y guiones de cada caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > De momento vamos bien, el error viene ahora:

```
Ingrese un caracter:
------------    (Me salen estos guiones y no se por que salen)
```

**¿Por qué sale ese error?**

Esto se debe porqué no estás limpiando el búfer del teclado.

**Comprobación:**

- Si el usuario ingresa la letra `o` y da `enter`, el búfer quedará con un salto de línea.
- Posteriormente la función `scanf` no se pausará porqué encontró un salto de línea en el búfer, entonces la variable `caracter` se queda con un `\n`.
- Como la variable `caracter` tiene guardado un salto de línea, la función `comparacion` se llamará y hará su respectiva acción. En este caso te imprimirá `------------` porqué la palabra `ornitorrinco` no tiene ningún caracter de tipo `'\n'`.

**Solución:**

```
    while (contador<intentos)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Ingrese un caracter: \n");
        scanf("%c",&caracter);
        //Limpiamos el búfer del teclado.
        while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
        j = 0;
        comparacion(j, letras,caracter);
    }
```

Por cierto, la variable `ch` no la olvides declarar al principio del `main`.

> > Ingreso el caracter (letra r) y sale esto:

```
-r----rr----
```

> > Lo que yo quiero que salga, es esto:

`or---orr---o`

El problema es que la función `comparacion` está incompleta. Ya que no comprueba si una determinada cadena de la matriz `palabra2` tiene un caracter diferente al guion (`'-'`).

**Solución:**

```
void comparacion (int j, int letras, char caracter)
{
    while (letras > j)
    {
        //Si el caracter es diferente a 0 y diferente a un guion, pasamos a la siguiente iteración...
        if(palabras2[0][j] != 0 && palabras2[0][j] != '-') 
        {
            ++j;
            continue;
        }

        if (caracter == palabras[0][j])
        {

            palabras2[0][j]=caracter;
            ++j;
        }
        else
        {
            palabras2[0][j]='-';
            ++j;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",palabras2[0]);
}
```

Si te das cuenta, es necesario esta condición:

```
palabras2[0][j] != 0
```

Esto se debe porqué cada fila de la matriz `palabra2` está inicializado a 0 (como lo declaraste como global, el compilador le asigna ese valor por defecto).

Entonces si tú no colocas esa condición, esta restricción siempre daría como resultado un `true`:

```
palabras2[0][j] != '-'
```

El programa debería dar como máximo 6 intentos, con 5 no es suficiente y te lo comprobaré:

- **1ro intento:** Si el usuario ingresa la letra `o`, el resultado por pantalla sería:

```
o----o-----o
```

- **2do intento:** Si el usuario ingresa la letra `r`, el resultado por pantalla sería:

```
or---orr---o
```

- **3ro intento:** Si el usuario ingresa la letra `n`, el resultado por pantalla sería:

```
orn--orr-n-o
```

- **4to intento:** Si el usuario ingresa la letra `t`, el resultado por pantalla sería:

```
orn-torr-n-o
```

- **5to intento:** Si el usuario ingresa la letra `i`, el resultado por pantalla sería:

```
ornitorrin-o
```

Como ves, si la variable `intentos` se queda asignado en 5, quedará sobrando un guion. Si hubiese tenido como valor máximo un seis, no hubiera pasado eso.

Adicional a eso, también te faltó agregar el incremento de la variable `contador` en el bucle while del `main`.

```
    while (contador<intentos)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Ingrese un caracter: \n");
        scanf("%c",&caracter);
        while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
        j = 0;
        comparacion(j, letras,caracter);
        ++contador; //Hay que agregar esta línea, de lo contrario, habrá bucle infinito.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Como pongo en el comentario, la función en cada llamada, sustituye cada posición por el caracter dado, si es coincidente, o por un guión, si no lo es. 
Por eso, en la segunda llamada, vuelve a poner guiones donde ya tenías las letras "o".

Para solucionar esto podrías hacer dos cosas:

1.- Partir de que el array palabras2 ya esté relleno de guiones. De esta forma la función `comparación` sólo tendría que modificar las posiciones coincidentes:

```
char palabras2[20][13]={"------------"};
```

y

```
void comparacion (char caracter)
{
    int j=0;
    while (strlen(palabras[0])>j)
    {
        if (caracter==palabras[0][j])
        {
            palabras2[0][j]=caracter;
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf("%s",palabras2[0]);
}
```

o una algo más elegante, y es que sólo sustituya los caracteres por guiones en la primera llamada.

Te dejo la implementación de esta segunda forma.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char palabras[20][13]={"ornitorrinco"};
char palabras2[20][13];
void comparacion (char caracter, int primera_llamada)
{
    int pos=0;
    while (strlen(palabras[0])>pos)
    {
        if (caracter==palabras[0][pos])
        {
            palabras2[0][pos]=caracter;
        }
        else if (caracter!=palabras[0][pos] && primera_llamada==0)
        {
            palabras2[0][pos]='-';
        }
        pos++;
    }
    printf("%s",palabras2[0]);
}
int main()
{
    int contador=0,intentos;
    char caracter;
    intentos=5;
    while (contador<intentos)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("Ingrese un caracter: \n");
        scanf("%c",&caracter);
        //vaciar buffer
        char c;
        while((c=getchar())!= '\n');
        //llamar funcion
        comparacion(caracter,contador);
        contador++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Como consejo aparte, no lleves como parámetros valores que puedes averiguar dentro de la propia función. En tu versión de la función `void comparacion (int j,int letras,char caracter)`, `j` es un simple int que puedes definir dentro de la función, y `letras` es un valor que puedes averiguar también dentro de la función. Cuando más sencilla y "autónoma" sea la función, mejor.

Por último, si lo que quieres es tener varias palabras, entiendo que tengas un array bidimensional, pero si solo es una sóla palabra, te hubiera bastado con un array unidimensional:

`char palabras[13]={"ornitorrinco"};`